# Is there a relation between the number of LSTM units and the length of the sequence to be trained?

Tags: keras, lstm, keras-layer

I have programmed keras neural network to train on sequences. Does choosing the LSTM units in keras depend on length of the sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a set way of determining how many units you should have based on your input.

More units are a way of making the model more complex. Generally speaking, if the look back period for your neural network is longer, then you have more features to train on, which means a more complex model would be better suited for learning your data.

Personally, I like to use the number of timesteps in each sample as my number of units, and I decrease this number as I move deeper into the network.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the problem when I designed sports betting prediction engine with LSTM RNN.
There's a rule of thumb that helps for supervised learning problems. Please check this link. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw/1097#1097)

But in my opinion, there is still no correct method or formulus to calculate the number of neurons per layer and the number of hidden layers according to the training dataset yet.